# Rearranging headers in linregress python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I am using Linregress in Python to get slope, intercept, etc

The output is a csv file. However, the data output does not have headers in columns. The data output is as: slope=5.562, intercept=223.5 etc

An image is attached herewith with what I see in Jupyter notebook(left image) vs what I need to have the data as (right image). t is rearranging the data so that the headers are not seen horizontally but vertically.

[image]

Will be great if I can get help on this.

Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
res = df.groupby('Test_event')[['x','y']].apply(linregress).apply(pd.Series)

res.columns = ['slope','intercept','rvalue','pvalue','stderror']
```

Though the chained `apply`s are less than ideal

Example:

```
>>> df
   Test_event  x   y
0           5  1   4
1           5  1   5
2           5  2   6
3           6  3   8
4           6  4  10
5           6  5  11

>>> res = df.groupby('Test_event')[['x','y']].apply(linregress).apply(pd.Series)
>>> res.columns = ['slope','intercept','rvalue','pvalue','stderror']
>>> res
            slope  intercept    rvalue    pvalue  stderror
Test_event                                                
5             1.5   3.000000  0.866025  0.333333  0.866025
6             1.5   3.666667  0.981981  0.121038  0.288675
```

Alternatively you could do this, but I'm not sure it's more efficient:

```
res = (df.groupby('Test_event')
       .apply(lambda group: pd.Series(linregress(group['x'],group['y']))))

res.columns = ['slope','intercept','rvalue','pvalue','stderror']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It worked exactly. as needed :)

Comment: If I need to save file as xlsx rather than csv, then what to do?

Comment: You can take a look at [`pd.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: @scaul, both the methods work perfectly well. Thanks for the great help! Is there any specific method which is more preferable?

Comment: I put the second method because I don't like chaining 2 `apply` back to back, since it is a slow iterative method... But if it's a small-ish dataset, then it's not a problem. Honestly, I'm not so sure my second method will really speed it up so much.

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct. When I used the first method which I was using, Jupyter Notebook showed In[*] which indicates it is a slow process, correct?

Comment: However, using your second method, I never saw In[*]. That means it is more faster.